# Change response to Outlook meeting and add text

Tags: vba, email, outlook, meeting-request

I would like to change the response to a meeting, that I have accepted, to tentative and send text like "I'm sorry, but I cannot attend.".

Online, I found solutions that show how to accept, cancel, forward, and copy a meeting.

I also understood that I can open the message to edit before sending the reply with

```
Item.Respond(olMeetingTentative, False, False)
```

I would like to have it automated.

I tried the following

```vb
Sub tentativeOccurenceWithResponse()

Dim Item As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim response As Outlook.MeetingItem

For i = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set Item = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i)
    
    If TypeName(Item) = "AppointmentItem" Then
        
        If Item.ResponseRequested Then
            Set response = Item.Respond(olMeetingTentative, True)
            response.RTFBody = "Thank you for the invitation. Unfortunatelly, I cannot attend the meeting.\nPlease check my calendar for alternative time slots if my attendance is required."
            response.Send
        Else
            Item.MeetingStatus = olMeetingTentative
        End If
        
        Set Item = Nothing
    
    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry, you need to select an appointment"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The workflow:
I would like to go to my calendar and select meetings that I will not be able to join. Most of them are meeting serious or long time planned. Hence, it was not possible to react when I got the invitation.
I want to notify all Meeting organizers that I cannot attend, but I would like to get updates and might still be able to join in case of vacation changes. (So no decline here.)

Comment: I fiddled around and found out that my meeting requests that I used to test it were not creating a response (`Nothing`). I tested it with a regular meeting request and it worked quite well. I'm not using `RTFBody` but rather `Body`. But it works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to declare the item as a generic object because Outlook folders may contain different kind of items:

```
Dim Item As Object
```

Then in the loop you can check out the message class and only after making sure the item is an appointment you can cast it to the required type and process the item further.

```
For i = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set Item = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i)
    
    If TypeName(Item) = "AppointmentItem" Then
```

---

If you need to handle incoming items automatically you can handle the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. So, you are interested in processing meeting items only. To recognize the item you need to get an instance of the incoming Outlook item. Use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Also you may consider hooking up the [ItemAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd) event on the folder. The event is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. Note, this event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but I want to react to already accepted meetings not when they get into my inbox.

Comment: Have you tried to run the code under the debugger? Do you get any errors at runtime?